# prism - Unable to set binding for HeaderTemplate of TabItem

Tags: wpf, prism, prism-4

I have a UserControl named ProductEditView which I am adding to a region of my MainWindow (shell). I have a TabControl in Shell region to display the ProductEditView like below

```
<TabControl Name="tabEditProduct" 
            prism:RegionManager.RegionName="TabContent"

    <TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
    <Style TargetType="TabItem">
        <Setter Property="HeaderTemplate">
            <Setter.Value>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <DockPanel LastChildFill="True" >
                        <Button Width="16" Height="16" Command="{Binding Path=CloseTabCommand}" 
                                        DockPanel.Dock="Right" BorderThickness="0" Padding="0"
                                        BorderBrush="Transparent" Background="Transparent">
                            <Image Source="Images/close-icon.png" Width="14" Height="14" 
                                           HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="0"/>
                        </Button>
                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding ProductName}" 
                                           DockPanel.Dock="Left" Margin="0,0,10,0" />
                    </DockPanel>
                </DataTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
    </TabControl.ItemContainerStyle>
</TabControl>
```

In the TabItem's HeaderTemplate I am trying to display text from the Product Object using binding. Unfortunately the binding is not working, but I can display static text as header. **Is it possible to display the Header Text of Tab Item using binding like above?**

For completeness, I am also pasting the view to Edit Product that loads in the TabControl region as TabItem. The bindings for that are working well. Here is the ProductEditView

```
<UserControl x:Class="TextExisting.CoreModule.ProductEditView"
....

        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Center" DataContext="{Binding Path=Product}" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0">
        ....
            <TextBlock Text="Id" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="1" 
                     Text="{Binding Path=Id, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />

            <TextBlock Text="Product Name" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0"/>
            <TextBox Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="1" 
                     Text="{Binding Path=ProductName, NotifyOnValidationError=True, ValidatesOnExceptions=True}" />
            ....
        </Grid>
        <Button Command="{Binding SaveProductCommand}" Content="Save Product" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>

</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe add something like this
 `"{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}, Mode=FindAncestor}, Path=DataContext.ProductName}"`

This will travel up and find the datacontext of the usercontrol which carries the binding to your view model and its properties.

Here is a little cheat sheet that i use [WPF Cheat Sheet](http://www.nbdtech.com/Free/WpfBinding.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

[Here](http://blog.vivekmehta.com/2011/06/referencing-viewmodel-datacontext-in-prism/) is the link explaining how to bind in this scenario.

Comment: You link is broken and that is exactly the reason why link only answers are not welcome on Stack Overflow (although perhaps not so unwelcome when you posted your answer).

Comment: here's the link and the solution worked for me 
http://blog.vivekmehta.com/2011/06/referencing-viewmodel-datacontext-in-prism/

Comment: Both links are broken